# How to execute both the local as the global ajax events in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

Recently making the switch from [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), I am struggling with some basic issues.

I use several AJAX-requests in my application; for 95% of these requests, I'd like to have some global events executed, such as showing or hiding a loading indicator. Apart from the global functionality, every request should also have some custom code executed after it has completed.

It seems like the local [Ajax events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) override the global ones, once they are set. For example, see the following code:

```
// global events
$('#loader').bind('ajaxStart', function() { 
    // in this particular example, the ajaxStart() works fine, 
    // as it has not been overridden
    Loader.enable();
}).bind('ajaxComplete', function() { 
    // this section will not execute. when the local complete()
    // is removed, it will execute just fine
    Loader.disable();
} );

// local ajax event
$.ajax({
    type: $(element).attr('method'),
    url: $(element).attr('action'),
    data: $(element).serialize(),
    global: 'true',
    complete: function(data) {
        if (params.target && $('#' + params.target)) {
            $('#' + params.target).html(data.responseText);
        }
        Behaviour.apply();
});
```

In this particular case, the local complete() event seems to stop the global ajaxComplete() event from executing.

**Is there any way to execute both the local as the global ajax events?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you for the replies. Both of them at least helped me to re-evaluate my code time and time again.

**The problem and solution turned out to be quite simple:**

The `Behaviour.apply();` that was called in my local complete event triggered an error elsewhere, preventing the `complete()` function to finish correctly and effectively disabling the global `ajaxComplete()` event. Fixing this error also fixed my problem.

**This means that jQuery supports combining both *local* as *global* ajax events.**

Answer (score 4):

Just tried to run your code. Added the missing }); though. Worked like a charm. Calls were made in this order:

1. ajaxStart
2. complete
3. ajaxComplete

**Here is what I did:**

```
// local ajax event
$.ajax({
    ...
    global: 'true',
    complete: function(data) {
        ...
    }
}); // <=== This line here
```

Comment: Error has been fixed now, but was caused by an wrong paste. This does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it, but why aren't you creating a global method:

```
function globalAjaxComplete(data)
```

and call it from both the global and local event handler?

You could also define a class "ajaxEnabled" and do this:

```
$(".ajaxEnabled").bind("ajaxStart", 
   Function() { globalAjaxComplete(); });
```

Then you wouldn't need to call the global method every time.

Still don't know however why the local binding cancels the global one.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but it will undoubtly work. This would require me to use this structure for every AJAX-request, though, which does not really improve my code.